# SH404SEF : How to redirect a URL to home?

Tags: joomla-3.4, url, sef, seo, sh404sef

In my site I have installed **SH404SEF**. For my homepage, I use a **Single-Article menu item** that holds an article with title **Home Page**.

Now I am getting an issue with duplicate homepage URLs.

- The first one is the **`www.example.com`**
- The second is another one that SH404SEF creates, for the home-menu-item /article, with url: **`www.example.com/home-page`**

I am trying to find a way to redirect this second home-page url to the root, but I can't find the way to do this in SH404SEF.

How to redirect the `www.example.com/home-page` to `www.example.com` with SH404SEF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit tricky to do this redirection in SH404SEF.

Here is the practical steps to achieve that:

1. In **SH404SEF URL Manager**, find the SEF urls of the page that you want to redirect to homepage.
2. **Write** them down, to another file if there are more than 1, or if it's just a single one, copy it at the clipboard.  (e.g. copy paste to a text file).
3. Now **delete** those (the ones that want to add to the home page redirection) **SEF URLs** and their **duplicates** from SH404SEF urls list.
4. Click on the **SH404SEF Toolbar**, there is a button "**Home Page Meta**".
5. A Modal window opens. This holds data for the homepage.
6. Click the "**Aliases**" Tab.
7. In the **Aliases textarea field**, enter the SEF urls you kept from step2 above. One url per line.
8. Click "**Save & Close**".

You are done.
SH404SEF will re-create the same SEF URLs for the article you have assigned to your homepage, but this time it will be an alias of the actual home-page, resulting to a redirection to the index page of your site.

Answer (score 2):

**sh404SEF developer here**

The answer by FFrewin above is not correct. To redirect some URLs to home page, you simply:

1. Click on the "**Home page meta**" toolbar button on any page of sh404SEF control panel
2. In the popup, select the "**Aliases**" input box and list the URLs you want to redirect to home page, one per line.
3. Click **Save**

Comment: Hi and welcome. My answer isn't saying something totally different. However at the time I wrote this, I took into consideration the fact that SH404SEF was throwing errors when the aliases to be used for redirecting to home page were already in SH404SEF's database. The error was something like that alias already exists or similar. Can you confirm that with the current SH404SEF version you can directly enter aliases to be redirected to home if they already exist in the db, without getting this error message?

Comment: Hi. Your answer says something totally different, a procedure that should absolutely never be used, under no circumstances._I took into consideration the fact that SH404SEF was throwing errors when the aliases to be used for redirecting to home page were already in SH404SEF's database_ Getting an error was absolutely normal if you tried to do what you did. When you posted a support ticket (after writing this question and answer), we saw that you could not find the correct input box (Aliases on Home page meta).

Comment: What did I do? Input box for home page meta is accessible through the toolbar button. There is an aliases input box to enter aliases for urls that should redirect to home page. If an alias is already stored in the database, sh404 won't accept it as it says the alias already exists. So how to redirect that alias to the home page?